# Getting number from place value in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, numbers, dotnetnuke

I have a form set up that has Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday and Sunday. When populated into the SQL database it starts off with 7 0s, each 0 representing the day of the week and when a day of the week is selected a 1 in the correct place. For instance if Monday is selected the value would be 1000000, if Tuesday 010000, Wednesday 001000 etc. Users have the option to select multiple days so it could be 101000 for Monday and Wednesday or 1111111 for all days. What would be the best route to convert this into a sql query to say if the 1 is in the hundred thousands place that equals Monday and if the 1 is in 101000 the value is Monday and Wednesday?

Let me know, thanks!

Comment: I don't understand this question.  Are you asking about data formats in the database?  What does the underlying table look like?  Can you change it?

Comment: It's almost like a bitmask, but worse.

Comment: What does this have to do with `dotnetnuke`?

Comment: Why you don't just use seven bit columns, one for each day of the week?

Answer (score 2):

If 2012+ You can use concat().  Also included STUFF() for a "cleaner" string.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('1000000'),
('1100000'),
('0100000'),
('1111111')

Select *
      ,NewCol = stuff(
                concat(
                ', '+IIF(substring(SomeCol,1,1)='1','Monday'   ,null)
               ,', '+IIF(substring(SomeCol,2,1)='1','Tuesday'  ,null)
               ,', '+IIF(substring(SomeCol,3,1)='1','Wednesday',null)
               ,', '+IIF(substring(SomeCol,4,1)='1','Thursday' ,null)
               ,', '+IIF(substring(SomeCol,5,1)='1','Friday'   ,null)
               ,', '+IIF(substring(SomeCol,6,1)='1','Saturday' ,null)
               ,', '+IIF(substring(SomeCol,7,1)='1','Sunday'   ,null)
               ),1,2,'')
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol   NewCol
1000000   Monday
1100000   Monday, Tuesday
0100000   Tuesday
1111111   Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday
```

> **EDIT - For 2008**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('1000000'),
('1100000'),
('0100000'),
('1111111')

Select *
      ,NewCol = stuff(
                case when substring(SomeCol,1,1)='1' then ', Monday'    else '' end
               +case when substring(SomeCol,2,1)='1' then ', Tuesday'   else '' end
               +case when substring(SomeCol,3,1)='1' then ', Wednesday' else '' end
               +case when substring(SomeCol,4,1)='1' then ', Thursday'  else '' end
               +case when substring(SomeCol,5,1)='1' then ', Friday'    else '' end
               +case when substring(SomeCol,6,1)='1' then ', Saturday'  else '' end
               +case when substring(SomeCol,7,1)='1' then ', Sunday'    else '' end
               ,1,2,'')
 From  @YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this however I keep getting several errors like the stuff function requires 4 arguments, there's an incorrect syntax near the first IIF and an incorrect syntax near the substring. Could there be something I'm missing?

Comment: @ndavern No syntax errors.  Just copied, pasted, and executed.  Are you not on 2012+ ?

Comment: @ndavern You can see it run here at dbFiddle  http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=5197fc1a19897972ebec6e477219114d

Comment: Just checked, actually running 2008 :(

Comment: @ndavern See Updated Answer

Answer (score 1):

Sounds quite odd... but perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
declare @var varchar(64) = '1010111'

select
    isnull(case when left(@var,1) = 1 then 'Monday' end,'')
    + ' ' +
    isnull(case when substring(@var,2,1) = 1 then 'Tuesday' end,'')
    + ' ' +
    isnull(case when substring(@var,3,1) = 1 then 'Wednesday' end,'')
    + ' ' +
    isnull(case when substring(@var,4,1) = 1 then 'Thursday' end,'')
    + ' ' +
    isnull(case when substring(@var,5,1) = 1 then 'Friday' end,'')
    + ' ' +
    isnull(case when substring(@var,6,1) = 1 then 'Saturday' end,'')
    + ' ' +
    isnull(case when right(@var,1) = 1 then 'Sunday' end,'')
```

Comment: I wrote the same :D